# Media Queries with resolution is overwriting the default styles

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, media-queries, scss-mixins

I have default styles:
`.rightpage{ position: relative }`

and media query with resoltution of `150%` or more:
`@media (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) { .rightPane { position: fixed; } }`

Outcome: but it is giving priority to
 `position: fixed;`
even on lower resolution, basically in all resolution

Expected: When resolution is less than `150%` then it should have this priority :
`position: relative`
& and when the resolution is more than `150%` or more then it should have this priority `position: fixed;`

Comment: The default style is on `.rightpage` and the override on `.rightPane`, is that a typo?

Comment: Here’s a test playground: when zoom/resolution is 150% or bigger, the background becomes blue. https://jsfiddle.net/9cu3oz0p/

Comment: its type, I tried in different styles also it doesnot work according to screen resolution. Did you try, is yours working? if so, could you so me how you did it?

Comment: Sorry, I tried again, in another project it worked :
@media only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi) and (max-width: 1280px) {
    .dark-theme {
        color: white;
        .s1{
          background-color: #ea127b;
        }
      
      }
}

thanks for the help : )